# HDMI-Ethernet extender

Tags: pi-3, hdmi, ethernet

I'm trying to redirect HDMI output of my Raspberry over ethernet to place a monitor 25m away from raspberry. I'm using a "Techly" HDMI extender like [this](https://www.techly.com/en_ty/amplifier-hdmi-full-hd-up-to-60m-of-cable-cat-6-6a-7.html).

My connection scheme is similar to this:

```
      /----------\                                            +----------+
      |          |  HDMI   +----+     25m    +----+   HDMI    |          |
      |  Raspb   |---------|  S |------------| R  |-----------| Monitor  |
      |          |         +----+  Ethernet  +----+ DVI Cable |          |
      \----------/                                            +----------+
```

`S = HDMI Sender`

`R = HDMI Reciver`

But when I turned on my Raspberry the monitor didn't show anything, so I tried a connection like this:

```
      /----------\           +----------+
      |          |    HDMI   |          |
      |  Raspb   |-----------| Monitor  |
      |          | DVI Cable |          |
      \----------/           +----------+
```

With this configuration works and if I switch back to the first one, the monitor after the "Receiver" shows the correct output.

I tried also a connection with an HDMI splitter like this:

```
      /----------\                                                              +----------+
      |          |  HDMI   +----+     HDMI    +----+      25m    +----+   HDMI  |          |
      |  Raspb   |---------| Sp |-------------|  S |-------------| R  |---------| Monitor  |
      |          |         +----+             +----+   Ethernet  +----+   DVI   |          |
      \----------/            |                                                 +----------+
                              | D
                            H | V
                            D | I
                            M | 
                            I | C
                              | a
                              | b
                              | l
                              | e
                              |
                        +----------+
                        |          |
                        | Monitor  |
                        |          |
                        +----------+
```

`Sp = Splitter`

But it didn't work. I'm using `hdmi_force_hotplug=1` option on my `/boot/config.txt`, I also tried changing:

- `config_hdmi_boost` option in `/boot/config.txt`
- HDMI cable
- Raspberry
- Ethernet cable
- `hdmi-safe` (suggested in comments)

I also tried with a notebook and the connection worked succesfully.
I think that the problem is a misconfiguration of the Raspberry that is running "Debian Jessie".
What am I missing?

Comment: You could try to disable EDID and force a specific mode instead. Also done in config.txt. https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt/video.md

Comment: You are using a Cat6 or better? And please change the URL to point to the english page!

Comment: Had similar issues in the past, resolved them by setting fixed resolution in raspi-config.

Comment: @MatsK link fix'd

Comment: @pieterdp I'm using
`hdmi_group=1`
`hdmi_mode=16` to force 1080p/60Hz

Comment: @Janka i also tried with `hdmi_safe = 1` but it still not work